# What was the first 6 wheeler Mercedes Benz made?

Tags: mercedes-benz, history

Was the first six-wheeler Mercedes Benz produced this one...

[image: Mercedes Benz Six Wheeler]

or this one...

[image: Mercedes Benz six-wheeler]

The promotional material for the modern one wants you to believe it is the first. Although I'm uncertain if that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has this article about the [Mercedes-Benz W31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_W31) pictured.

> The Mercedes-Benz W31 type G4 was a German three-axle off-road vehicle first produced by Mercedes-Benz as a staff/command car for the Wehrmacht in 1934. The cars were designed as a seven-seat touring car or closed saloon, and were mainly used by upper echelons of the Nazi regime in parades and inspections, as they were deemed too expensive for general Army use.
> . . .
> Of the 57 cars produced, at least three exist in original form.

From their connection to the Nazi Party, perhaps MB isn't too keen to push the history as a marketing ploy.

---

The Range Rover had six wheel 6x4 versions. The difference with the early Mercedes Benz is that the rear axle was unpowered instead of the front axle, however [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Rover#Utility_vehicles) has

> **Utility vehicles**
> The first-generation Range Rover served as the base for specialist utility vehicles. These included the Carmichaels International six-wheel Fire Tender. This was a two-door model with an extended chassis and a third "lazy" axle added. Designed for small airfield use, it had a water-pump mounted on the front bumper driven directly by the V8's crankshaft. The MoD purchased them for the RAF, this version was called the TACR2. Carmichaels was contracted to supply the modified chassis and the fire-fighting body was supplied and mounted by Gloster-Saro. These were four-door versions using an internally mounted water-pump driven by a gearbox PTO. At least one of these (at Duxford IWM) has been converted into a **full 6x6** by linking a drive-through unit to the two rear axles.
>
> [image]
> <sub>Caption: YAM Range Rover Airport Fire Tender</sub>

---

Also [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/mercedes-isnt-the-first-to-build-a-six-wheeled-car-2014-4?r=US&IR=T) reports:

> **Mercedes-Benz Isn't The First Automaker To Build A Six-Wheeled Car**
>
> [image]
> <sub>Caption: A 1973 six-wheeled Range Rover</sub>

Comment: Your final sentence said a lot, and is quite possibly more real than you'd think. Nice find and +1.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've now noticed that the 1934 model was not 6x6 but 6x4. The front wheels are not driven.

Comment: The question asked, "First **six wheeler**" ... I think you have it covered.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I suppose the "promotional material for the modern one" is carefully worded. I [had a look](https://www.mercedes-benz.com/en/innovation/amg-6x6/), but could not find any claim from MB of that kind.